Woman with a bandaged head in a comedy from probably 2004-2011
I think the main character is a young man, maybe in high school. He is visited by his female neighbor who has a bandage on her head. She sits on the couch and the back of her head touches it and when she get up there's a string of blood between the head and the couch. The guy tries to hide it.
And I think it's in this movie that there is a handicapped man over 40 that mistreats and is mistreated by another man that lives with him, probably his brother.

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

You're describing a strange scene from My Boss's Daughter from 2003 in which Ashton Kutcher wanders into the wrong house. From the Movie Spoiler:

Tom sees O.J. [the owl] and runs into some house. There the family mistakes him for their daughter's date, Albert. She comes down and has this bandage over her head because she was shot in the head. Tom explains that he's not Albert but they think he just said that not to go out with her. They kick him out.

The injured daughter is played by Ever Carradine. Her dad's cousin George is a quadriplegic blind man who's about 50 something and berates Tom and the dad verbally abuses him and kicks his wheelchair (it's that kind of movie). Here's the trailer:




Thank you! That's definitely the movie with the girl with bandeged head! XD But, for what I watched from this movie now, it's probably not the one with the handicapped man, who is a wheelchair user. So, should I accept your answer as the right? And should I make another question for the handicapped man scene only? I'm new here, sorry.

You're welcome. :) I tracked down the first scene with the injured girl and there's definitely an old blind relative in a wheelchair there that her dad abuses (I added it to the answer). If that's still not it, you can always put up another question.
